# Can anyone help me to solve an ambiguous error when search?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, list, search

```
$students = Student::select('students.*', 'users.email')->join('users', 'students.user_id', 'users.id')->orderBy("id", "desc")->skip($page * $pageSize)->take($pageSize);

    if (request('se') != "" || request('se') != null) {
        $se = request('se');
        $se = str_replace("+", " ", $se);
        $students = $students
            ->where(function ($q) use ($se) {
                $q->where('students.student_number', 'like', '%' .$se. '%')
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`)"), 'LIKE', '%' . $se . '%')
                    ->orWhere('students.gender', $se)
                    ->orWhere('students.phone', 'like', '%' .$se. '%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' .$se. '%');
            });
    }
    $students = $students->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

when I search in the list I got `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'first_name' in where clause is ambiguous` error.
This got when join the table because both students and users table have first name and last name columns, but I have retrieved from only students table, I didn't understand why this appears again!
Are there any better solution for this?

Comment: What's the problem with changing to `students.first_name`?

Comment: tried but no improvements

Answer (score 0):

Change the `first_name` and `last_name` to `students.first_name` and `students.last_name` respectively

Comment: Given that's the only mention of `first_name`, means the error must of changed. So it is an improvement. So what's the new error?

Comment: if changes added into `select` got `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'first_name' in where clause is ambiguous `.


if changes made like this `$q->whereRaw("CONCAT(students.first_name,' ',students.last_name) like ?", '%' . $se . '%');`

error is `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.first_name' in 'where clause' `